# While-loop with an or-condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want it to stop once one of the variables gets to the desired number. Why does this code wait until **both** variables equal 20 or greater to end?

```
z = 20
x = 1
y = 0
while x < z or y < z:
    inp = int(input('enter a number'))
    if x > y:
        y += inp
    elif y > x:
        x += inp
    print(x, y)
```

or using something like these examples just keeps adding and never stops:

```
while x != z or y != z:    
while x or y < z:
while x or y != z:
```

Comment: This is how or work ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the loop must stop when *at least* one of the variables is `>= z`, then you must use `and` to connect the conditions:

```
while x < z and y < z:
```

In your code, by using `or` you state that as long as one of the variables is `< z`, the loop must continue - and that's not what you want.

Comment: God I feel dumb, that makes so much more sense. Thanks mate.

Comment: After 15 minutes @ÓscarLópez :)