# How to write a while loop that will run base in hours

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm creating a test for Google Assistant based on while loop. The code will play a long mp3 file and I'm try to identify if the assistant will do a false trigger and count how many times.

I'm running on pycharm/pytest and getting the trigger status by UIAutomator provided by Google.

```
import android
import time

play_music(music.mp3)
start_time = time.time()
trigger = 0
hours = 1
command_timeout = hours * 60 * 60
while trigger < 3 or time.time() - start_time < command_timeout:
   if trigger_screen.is_in_screen():
       trigger += 1
       time.sleep(10)
stop_music()
```

The conditions to stop the loop is 3 false triggers or one hour of test, but the loop isn't stop after one hour of test, could someone help me?

Comment: Why is your code indented after start_time

Comment: Are you sure it's going inside the if?

Comment: Can you confirm that your programis running the while loop and playing the music simultaneously?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While-loop with an or-condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867007/while-loop-with-an-or-condition) ... and [multiple conditions with while loop in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578277/multiple-conditions-with-while-loop-in-python)

Comment: Side-note: If at all possible, you should move to Python 3, not just because Python 2 is reaching end-of-life at the end of this year, but because it would let you replace `time.time()` with `time.monotonic()`, which will behave correctly even if your phone's time changes (e.g. due to network time sync).

Comment: If there is a pending edit when you want to edit, accept it as long as it isn't destructive and then add your edit rather than just editing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the `or` in your code with `and` like shown below:

```
import android
import time

play_music(music.mp3)
start_time = time.time()
    trigger = 0
    hours = 1
    command_timeout = hours * 60 * 60
    while trigger < 3 and time.time() - start_time < command_timeout:
        if trigger_screen.is_in_screen():
            trigger += 1
            time.sleep(10)
stop_music()
```

Bassically the code you wrote continues the loop as long as one of the conditions is met, which explains why your music continued to play (less than 3 triggers so the loop still runs)

Comment: The conditions to stop the loop is 3 false triggers or one hour of test, but the loop isn't stop after one hour of test.

Comment: I think you forgot to actually change the `or` to an `and` in the code (it should be `while trigger < 3 and time.time() - start_time < command_timeout:`). I fixed it, but if I misunderstood, feel free to revert.

Comment: @ThiagoMoura: That's the point; you want it to stop when either condition is not met, but by using `or`, you only stop when *both* conditions aren't met. The loop as you wrote it stops only when you've had three false triggers *and* it's been an hour. As written, if `trigger < 3` returns `True`, the loop continues without even checking the time (because `or` is satisfied by the first truthy result).

Comment: @ThiagoMoura Your right, accidently forgot to change the code, hoping the explanation below made it clear for him.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an `or` statement when you should be using an `and` statement:

```
while trigger < 3 and time.time() - start_time < command_timeout:
```

With your current code, the while loop only terminates when BOTH conditions are
`False`, when you really want it to terminate when either one or the other is `False`.

Comment: The conditions to stop the loop is 3 false triggers or one hour of test, but the loop isn't stop after one hour of test.

Comment: @ThiagoMoura: That's the point of the answer; you *need* `and` in that case. See [my other comment for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56994147/hot-to-write-a-while-loop-that-will-run-base-in-hours#comment100524514_56994816).